# Exponentiation of Sets Proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I am currently attempting to dive into Axiomatic Set Theory but before that I am trying to get a good solid base of Naive Set Theory.

I am stuck on how to prove the following three Theorems:

If $ X^{Y \cup Z} \sim  X^Y$ x $X^Z$

If ($X_1$ x $X_2$)$^Y$ $\sim X_1^Y$ x $X_2^Y$

If $X^{Y x Z} \sim (X^Y)^Z $

Where $\sim$ means that there exists a bijection.

My attempt at the first proof:

If $ F \in X^{Y \cup Z} $ then $ F: {Y \cup Z} \to X $

where $ f_1 : Y \to X$ and $f_2 : Z \to X $

and $ G \in$ $X^Y$ x $X^Z$
where $ g_1: Y \to X $ and $g_2: Z \to X $
then $G(g_1 , g_2) = h $

I am currently unsure as to what g is.

My attempt at the second proof:

If $ f \in $ ($X_1$ x $X_2$)$^Y$ then $ f: Y \to$ ($X_1$ x $X_2$)
and $ g \in $ $X_1^Y$ x $X_2^Y$  then $ g: $  ?

My attempt at the third proof:

Let $\phi: X^{Y x Z} \to (X^Y)^Z $

then $\phi(F)=G, G\vert_y (z) = H, H(y)= F(y,z)$.

Comment: Are $Y$ and $Z$ disjoint?

Comment: Yes, and if it were the case that they were not, from my understanding, you can create a bijections that will make said sets dijoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $F: X^Y \times X^Z \rightarrow X^{Y \cup Z}$ such that if $f: Y \rightarrow X$ and $g: Z \rightarrow X$ then $F(f,g)=h$ where $h: Y \cup Z \rightarrow X$ is such that $\left.h\right|_Y = f$ and $\left.h\right|_Z = g$.

Take $F_2: X_1^Y \times X_2^Y \rightarrow (X_1 \times X_2)^Y$ such that if $f: Y \rightarrow X_1$ and $g: Y \rightarrow X_1$ then $F_2(f,g)=h$ where $h: Y \rightarrow X_1 \times X_2$ is such that $h(y) = (f(y), g(y))$.

Comment: Thank you.  Thinking about it a little more I started editing it and then saw this response.

Comment: The third one is harder, can't think in a bijection right now.

Comment: @Antioquia3943 BIG ERROR.  I meant the cartesian product of the sets, not the union.  The union would never work.

Comment: Actually i think it's correct with union. If they're disjoint. Disjoint union if they're not.

Comment: @ziggurism I am speaking in reference to the third Theorem.  I initially had $X^{Y\cupZ$ but I meant cartesian product of the sets.

Comment: Oh ok. Why don't you get the first problem before moving on to the third?

Comment: The third one seemed a bit easier for me to grasp. I was just unsure as to how to handle the cross of two exponentiated sets. I just edited my attempt for the third one. I would appreciate if someone could look it over.

Answer (score 1):

Well if $f$ is defined on $Y\cup Z$ then $f$ can take as input elements of both $Y$ and $Z$. To construct an element of $X^Y\times X^Z$ you need two maps, one which acts on elements of $Y$ and another which acts on elements of $Z$.

For the second attempt, again you need to create a pair of maps. One from $Y$ to $X_1$ and another from $Y$ to $X_2$. Remember that $f$ will give you pairs of elements in $X_1\times X_2$.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped get the ball rolling, I just edited my question.

Comment: You have to define the map $f_1$. What value should $f_1(y)$ take for $y\in Y$? Remember to use your given data $F$.